# Overwrite variable path with defined path

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-routing

I'm using fos userbundle to create pages for the route `/profile`. Now I want to be able to see other users profiles too so I created my own controller generating `/profile/{username}`.

The problem I'm having now is that I **can't** use the fos userbundle path `/profile/edit`. It does show the path in `route:debug`

Is there any way to make an exception for the route /profile/edit?

here's my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile/{username}")
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
public function showOtherAction($username){

    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('DigitalArtLabBundle:User')->findOneByUsername($username);
    $sessions = $em->getRepository('DigitalArtLabBundle:checkin')->findLastSessions($user->getUsername() );

    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'ses' => $sessions
    ));

}
```

thank's ahead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should paste your routing configuration for that route after including routing configuration from `FOSUserBundle`. And then the first matched route (from `FOSUserBundle`) will be used.

Example `routing.yml` for your case:

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Be aware: you can't have user with name "edit" (and other reserved route paths) in this case.

Comment: Thanks! this was the solution!